# "overloaded member function not found" reference

Tags: c++, function, class, methods, reference

I have a problem with my code. I tried to use reference to take my variables from method to main() function and i get this error : "overloaded member function not found". Please Help! :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;



class Tworzenie_postaci {
public: 
    Tworzenie_postaci();

    string Nazwa_Postaci();

    int Wiek_Postaci();

    int Staty_Postaci(int Final_Postac_Sila, int Final_Postac_Inteligencja);

    int Staty_Postaci();
private:


};

Tworzenie_postaci::Tworzenie_postaci() {


}

string Tworzenie_postaci::Nazwa_Postaci()
{
    string wpisz_nazwa;
    cout << "Wybierz imie dla swojej postaci:\n";
    cin >> wpisz_nazwa;
    cout << "Nazwa twojej postaci to:\n" << wpisz_nazwa<< "\n";
    return wpisz_nazwa;

}

int Tworzenie_postaci::Wiek_Postaci()
{
    int wiek;
    cout << "Ile twoja postac ma lat?\n";
    cin >> wiek;
    cout << "Wiec twoja postac ma " << wiek << " lat\n";
    return wiek;
}


void Tworzenie_postaci::Staty_Postaci(int& _Postac_Sila, int& _Postac_Inteligencja) {
    int Postac_Sila;
    int Postac_Inteligencja;

        cout << "Ile twoja postac ma sily? :\n";
        cin >> Postac_Sila;
        cout << "Twoja postac ma " << Postac_Sila << " sily \n";

        cout << "Ile twoja postac ma inteligencji? : \n";
        cin >> Postac_Inteligencja;
        cout << "Twoja postac ma "<< Postac_Inteligencja << " inteligencji \n";
            _Postac_Sila = Postac_Sila;
            _Postac_Inteligencja = Postac_Inteligencja;

}


int main()
{
    Tworzenie_postaci Postac;
    string Final_Imie;
    int Final_Wiek;
    int Final_Postac_Sila;
    int Final_Postac_Inteligencja;

        Final_Imie = Postac.Nazwa_Postaci();

        Final_Wiek = Postac.Wiek_Postaci();

        Postac.Staty_Postaci(Final_Postac_Sila, Final_Postac_Inteligencja);

        cout << "\n " << Final_Postac_Sila;


    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for polish names of variables or functions but it is easier for me that way :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is declared as:

```
  int Staty_Postaci(int Final_Postac_Sila,
                    int Final_Postac_Inteligencja);
```

It is defined as:

```
void Tworzenie_postaci::Staty_Postaci(int& _Postac_Sila,
                                      int& _Postac_Inteligencja)
{
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the types in the declaration and the definition don't match.
Change one of them to match the other.

Also, the return types must match.

Comment: Changed that. Still the same problem

Comment: @MikołajPopieluch I see two `Staty_Postaci`s in the class but only one outside it.